# I try to make a webvr panorama, but my image seems to be wrong

Tags: webvr

I'm making a webvr demo ( www.huiswijn.com/webvr ) It uses a single image that i rendered out. The code works just fine f I point to the google demo image ( https://storage.googleapis.com/vrview/examples/coral.jpg ), but not with my own.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Megaplex</title>
   <script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/vrview/2.0/build/vrview.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id='vrview'></div>
   <script>
  window.addEventListener('load', onVrViewLoad)
  function onVrViewLoad() {
    var vrView = new VRView.Player('#vrview', {
      width: 300,
      height: 300,
      preview: 'http://huiswijn.com/webvr/images/slaapkamer_vr.jpg',
      image: 'http://huiswijn.com/webvr/images/slaapkamer_vr.jpg',
      is_stereo: true
    });
  }
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Error message: 
Render: Unable to load texture from "http://huiswijn.com/webvr/images/slaapkamer_vr.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

You've got the reason in your console:

> three.min.js:424 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://storage.googleapis.com/vrview/2.0/index.html?preview=http://huiswijn.com/webvr/images/slaapkamer_vr.jpg&image=http://huiswijn.com/webvr/images/slaapkamer_vr.jpg&is_stereo=true&' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://huiswijn.com/webvr/images/slaapkamer_vr.jpg'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

You have to host your image over HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks for this advice! Now I host it over https, but still there are errors. First I had a CORS error, wich i fixed by host the javascript on my own server. See www.tripledesign.nl

Comment: Have you tried an absolute path for your image? Also you can try another viewer, like [BIVROST 360WebPlayer](http://github.com/BIVROST/360WebPlayer) (disclamer: I'm the author of it)